# Error installing Rmagick on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

I followed the installation of ***RMagick*** for ***OSX:***
http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#osx

I have done the ***Imagemagick*** installation from ***John Maddux*** (solution to install *ImageMagick* on OSX without using *MacPorts*)

Here's my terminal window:

```
Suebphatt:~ suebphattleelertphong$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Suebphatt:~ suebphattleelertphong$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.3

Suebphatt:~ suebphattleelertphong$ gem -v
1.3.7

Suebphatt:~ suebphattleelertphong$ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for     inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
Suebphatt:~ suebphattleelertphong$
```

Thanks a lot for help,
Suebphatt

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you try homebrew, which is a great replacement for macports:

- http://brew.sh
- http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Once you get homebrew installed, you should be able to install imagemagick and rmagick very easily:

```
brew install imagemagick     # will take a while!
gem install rmagick
```

More info here:

http://www.codedrop.ca/blog/archives/214

and here:

http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/mverzilli/2010/05/19/install-the-rmagick-gem-in-the-painless-way-with-homebrewinstall-the-rmagick-gem-in-the-painless-way-with-homebrewinstall-the-rmagick-gem-in-the-painless-way-with-homebrewinstall-the-rmagick-gem-in/

UPDATE: (thanks to [JJD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356895/jjd) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7973760/356895))

Try to install without openpmp if you are having trouble with a chiliproject install:

```
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp
```

UPDATE X2: (thanks to [Ramon Araujo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428813/ramon-araujo)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290759/error-installing-rmagick-on-mac-os-x/4290798#comment17772421_4290798))

If you have previously installed imagemagick with homebrew, you will have to unlink it before you install again:

```
brew unlink imagemagick
```

Comment: Hi, bowsersenior,

Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try it and will let you know the result.

Comment: I tried to install [chiliproject](https://www.chiliproject.org) and successfully followed this advise to [install imagemagick without openmp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7973760/356895).

Comment: @JJD Thanks for the comment. I've updated my answer with your info.

Comment: Perfect, just one comment. I had imagemagick already installed using brew, so it asked me first to 'brew unlink imagemagick' before. After I did that, then I followed again your suggestions and it all went perfect! Thanks @bowsersenior.

Comment: Thanks @RamonAraujo, I have updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Updated my answer to include link to `brew.sh`

Answer (score 8):

Another think to watch out is the version of imagemagick.
I had ImageMagick version 6.8.0, which is the latest if you install from homebrew, and rmagick just does not compile with this version.
So do a

> convert --version

and make sure that your ImageMagick is 6.7 or less otherwise rmagick wont compile..

Comment: And to install a specific version (using homebrew)... https://coderwall.com/p/lqphzg

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this problem for a while, and the fix below (copied from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13967303/2484523) solved the issue (specifically the section about symbolic links).

rmagick has a problem working with imagemagick (>= 6.8.0-10) from homebrew.

You can either

update rmagick gem by

```
bundle update rmagick
```

or manually symbol link some dylib to make it work:

```
$ cd "`Magick-config --prefix`lib"
$ ln -s libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib
$ ln -s libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
$ ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

After that `gem install rmagick` should work.

Check the discussion about this in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/16625