# ERROR: Error installing rmagick on Redhat 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, redhat

I am trying to run my Rails application in Redhat7 but facing this error when I run bundle install:

> An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.4), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

When I run gem install rmagick, this is the error I am getting:

> [root@ip-172-12-13-148 MyProject]# gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing rmagick:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.4/ext/RMagick
> ```
>
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20160818-2119-1nvxrgu.rb extconf.rb checking for Ruby
>   version >= 1.8.5... yes checking for gcc... yes checking for
>   Magick-config... no checking for pkg-config... yes checking for
>   ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes Package MagickCore was not found
>   in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing `MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found Package MagickCore was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing`MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found Package MagickCore was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing `MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found Package MagickCore was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing`MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found checking for stdint.h... yes checking
>   for sys/types.h... yes checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
>
> Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.13.4/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.13.4/gem_make.out

I tried using

1. `yum install IMageMagick`and run bundle, but issue continues.
2. `[root@ip-172-12-13-148 MyProject]# yum install ImageMagick-devel`

then:

> Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
>
> No package ImageMagick-devel available.
>
> Error: Nothing to do Please help.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For RedHat try running this command

```
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

Refer - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7792909/4758119)

Comment: Getting this error:  **No package ImageMagick-devel available** . Updated this in question, please check.

Comment: I don't have any idea about redhat packages but check for the alternatives of **imagemagick** and **libmagick-dev**