# RMagick RVM installation failed

Tags: macos, imagemagick, rvm, rmagick, homebrew

I keep getting this error when I'm installing rmagick inside rvm.

```
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.
```

Here's my current setup:

```
Snow Leopard 10.6.7
XCode 3.2.6
RVM 1.6.1
Ruby Over RVM (ree1.8.7)
Homebrew 0.8
ImageMagick 6.6.9-4 c/o Homebrew
```

After installing imagemagick with Homebrew, I was able to install rmagick using the system ruby

```
rvm system
sudo gem install rmagick
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try uninstalling *ImageMagick* and reinstalling it as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7973760/356895) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290759/error-installing-rmagick-on-mac-os-x/4290798#4290798). And [here](https://gist.github.com/2763243) a similar installation instruction.

Answer (score 7):

I think that there was a problem with the imagemagick package from homebrew for a small period of time.  I just walked through re-installing rmagick on my system (also 10.6.7 with RVM).  First I re-installed imagick:

```
brew uninstall imagick
```

and then

```
brew install imagick
```

Finally I did

```
gem install rmagick
```

Which compiled with no problems.  I can't see why it would cause you problems but you don't need to use sudo when use rvm unless you installed RVM as root.

Answer (score 1):

RMagick expects for Homebrew to provide certain symlinks which don't exit, [causing a whole lotta problems](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16625).

You can run [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4583529) to create the symlinks specific to your ImageMagick installation that are needed for RMagick to work.

Comment: Saved my day. All the other manual links did not work for me.