# Error installing rmagick gem on osx lion with homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac Rmagick wont install with Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961091/mac-rmagick-wont-install-with-xcode-4-2)

I can't seem to install the rmagick gem on osx. I've installed imagemagick via homebrew after downgrading Xcode from 4.2 to 4.1. Here's my output from `rvmsudo gem install rmagick`. From the output of the `mkmf.log` it looks like a linker issue. I've seen on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h) for linux that rvm couldn't find the path for imagemagick. Any suggestions?

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
    extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    checking for clang... yes
    checking for Magick-config... yes
    checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
    checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
    checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
    /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

And here's the output of mkmf.log

```
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

    --------------------

    find_executable: checking for clang... -------------------- yes

    --------------------

    find_executable: checking for Magick-config... -------------------- yes

    --------------------

    checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... -------------------- yes

    --------------------

    checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... -------------------- yes

    --------------------

    "clang -o conftest -I/Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0 -I/Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.  -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/neil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -L/usr/X11/lib    -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -L/usr/X11/lib -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl  -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
    ld: library not found for -lgomp
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include "ruby.h"
    2: 
    3: int main() {return 0;}
    /* end */
```