# os installing rmagick gem error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, bundler, rmagick

I upgraded to Lion and am now seeing an error when installing the rmagick gem as part of a bundle:

```
"gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.  -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -L/usr/X11/lib    -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -L/usr/X11/lib -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl  -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: library not found for -llcms
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

I have upgraded homebrew and uninstalled and re-installed imagemagick to no avail.

Comment: You can find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290759/error-installing-rmagick-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I already have homebrew installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventual answer found here:
[Mac Rmagick won't install with Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961091/mac-rmagick-wont-install-with-xcode-4-2/7964605#7964605)

using Homebrew:

```
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp
```