# Cannot install gem RMagick after upgrade to Mac OS X Maverick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rmagick

I have some issue about rails, after i upgrade to new version of mac os x Maverick. my rmagick wont install. 
I've already follow to install imagemagick 6.8.0-10 
and add 
    $ cd "`Magick-config --prefix`lib"
    $ ln -s libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib
    $ ln -s libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
    $ ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib

and install gem install rmagick.
and got this message.

Fetching: rmagick-2.13.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for xcrun... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.ou
```

t

Comment: Try to look this.and follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290759/error-installing-rmagick-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Yep, just installed with `brew` a few days ago on Mavericks – everything works great!

Comment: still got the same error @p11y

Comment: use [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/) for install rmagick

Comment: i already to use hemebrew but got error too @PhilidorGreen [error-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425147/error-installing-rmagick)

Comment: `xcode` and `command line tools` already installed?

Comment: yes already using xcode 5.0.1 and command line tools using iTerm.. @PhilidorGreen

Comment: whats this mean  `command line tools using iTerm`?

Comment: i told u asking me about command line tools...im using that @PhilidorGreen

Comment: command line tools installed through Xcode?

Comment: ow..not yet, but im downloading it now. @PhilidorGreen

Comment: i already install it @PhilidorGreen

Comment: still got same error. `Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes` @PhilidorGreen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56329/discussion-between-philidor-green-and-agstwn21).